# After sitefinity upgrade script getting conflict

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, upgrade, sitefinity

Need some help with a conflict issue in sitefinity. I have a page created in Sitefinity. On the master page, we have already added the jquery from CDN, and in the page using some javascript widget provided by Sitefinity we have  added the matchheight script and method calling the script as follows `

```
$(function() {
    $('.box0').matchHeight();
    $('.box').matchHeight();
    $('.box2').matchHeight();
});`
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you including script tags?

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/javascript-widget-mvc

"NOTE: You do not need to add <script> tag, since it is automatically added."

Comment: no,script tags was generated by sitefinity